# ReSharper Custom Conversion - AutoProperty to MvxProperty

Tags: mvvmcross, automated-refactoring, resharper-7.1

in our architecture, we have a bunch of models like this

```
public class UserModel
{
    public string FirstName {get;set;}
}
```

and since we're using MvvmCross for our view models, we need our properties to look like this

```
public class UserViewModel: MvxViewModel
{
    private string _firstName;
    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return _firstName; }
        set { _firstName = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => FirstName); }
    }
}
```

Now I've already got an R# template to write my own mvx properties by simply typing `propmvx`, but I still need to type in the type and the name.

I'm wondering if there's a way to setup a custom conversion template in order to have the <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd> context menu to have a second option... something like

> - [T]o property with backing field
> - To [M]vx property with backing field

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is possible, even without creating any custom plugins or patterns, by using [ReSharper Annotations](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Code_Analysis__External_Annotations.html). I have recently recorded a webinar with JetBrains, demonstrating exactly how to solve this with annotations. You can watch it [here](http://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2014/02/18/webinar-recording-and-qa-resharper-secrets-with-igal-tabachnik/).

Short answer: the method

```
public void RaisePropertyChanged<T>(Expression<Func<T>> property)
```

of [`MvxNotifyPropertyChange.cs`](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/v3.1/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross/ViewModels/MvxNotifyPropertyChanged.cs) needs to be annotated with the [`NotifyPropertyChangedInvocatorAttribute`](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Reference__Code_Annotation_Attributes.html#NotifyPropertyChangedInvocatorAttribute), and then you could simply Alt-Enter on the property, and change it to a **Property with change notificaton**.

Now, since you can't (or don't want to) modify the source code of MvvmCross, you could apply those annotations externally, via XML. Take a look at the **ExternalAnnotations** directory, located in your ReSharper installation directory. It contains a bunch of external annotations for other MVVM frameworks. It's a simple XMLDoc format, so you could create an XML for MvvmCross and write the appropriate methods there. After that, save the file under a directory `MvvmCross` (or however the assembly is called), reload your solution, and it should just work!

For more information, please watch my webinar (link above), or [JetBrains help](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Code_Analysis__External_Annotations.html)

Here's an External Annotations file that will work with that method.

**[Cirrious.MvvmCross.ExternalAnnotations.xml](https://gist.github.com/ChaseFlorell/9648056)**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<assembly name="Cirrious.MvvmCross">

  <member name="M:Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels.MvxNotifyPropertyChanged.RaisePropertyChanged``1(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression{System.Func{``0}})">
    <attribute ctor="M:JetBrains.Annotations.NotifyPropertyChangedInvocatorAttribute.#ctor" />
  </member>

</assembly>
```

And here it is in action:

[image: Woot!]

Comment: I wouldn't recommend saving the xml file in the product directory. That directory won't be around in 8.2 (annotations are now packaged as an extension). Save the xml file side-by-side with the mvvmcross dll, or package it up as it's own extension - http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/NETCOM/1.06+Packaging+%28R8%29

Comment: Yes, @citizenmatt is right! But I didn't want to specify it here since it was tagged with "ReSharper-7.1", so...

Comment: @citizenmatt I'm using R#7.1 but we will be upgrading soon. What I've done for now is created a `ViewModelBase` that extends `MvxViewModel` From there I `new` the `RaisePropertychanged` and annotate it accordingly.

Comment: Followup question, is it possible to change the template? I see the `NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator` in the annotations file, but I'm not sure what template it's using... I'd just like to reformat it a bit.

Comment: It's not possible to change the generated code - it doesn't use a template, but generates it on the fly. This is due to the many different ways of raising change notifications - strings, lambdas, ref parameters, etc. This would be too crazy for a template to handle.

Comment: I gotcha @citizenmatt. So if I go the XML route, can I avoid dropping the annotations.cs file as well as the `[NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]` attribute in my code? I'm hoping to be able to mange this without any R# "tools" code in my source.

Comment: Yes, providing the code you want to annotate is living in a referenced dll

Comment: ok, so I can just take the MVX dll, create an xml file and all is right in the world. Working on it now! thanks.